# Going back one page in React actually just removes the search from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have params that I store in a local state and whenever that state changes I am triggering fetching of data because I have filters on that page. The problem is that when each time params change, so does the search in url and it appears that it pushes that page in history so when I do `navigate(-1)` I remain on the same page but without search params.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
        navigate('?' + new URLSearchParams(params).toString())
        dispatch(getSingleDBEmployee(params))
    }
    return () => {
        dispatch(clearSingleDBEmployee())
    }
}, [params])
```

Here, each time I select a filter, I trigger refetching data based on the new criteria

Comment: that sounds like the expected behavior of the methods you're using. if you want the back button to not undo a state change to the URL but rather go back a page, then you need to replace the state of the URL rather than navigate. If you can let us know what navigation library you're using, then if you can't find the method that does that, we can help you more

Comment: ++ generally it is cleaner and less error-prone to rely on the router to store navigation state than to futz around keeping it in the component state.